# javascript xml filter results

Tags: javascript, xml

< os owner="microsoft" version="windows xp"  link="microsft.com/windows98" information="microsoft.com/windows98/more_info" / >
< os owner="microsoft" version="windows 2000"  link="microsft.com/windows2000" information="microsoft.com/windows2000/more_info"  / >
< os owner="microsoft" version="windows windows 7"  link="microsft.com/windows7" information="microsoft.com/windows7/more_info"  / >
< os owner="Fedora" version="Fedora core 4" link="fedora.com/4" information="fedora.com/4/more_info" / >
< os owner="Fedora" version="Fedora core 5" link="fedora.com/5" information="fedora.com/6/more_info" / >
< os owner="Fedora" version="Fedora core 6" link="fedora.com/6" information="fedora.com/6/more_info" / >
< os owner="Fedora" version="Fedora core 7" link="fedora.com/7" information="fedora.com/7/more_info" / >
< os owner="Fedora" version="Fedora core 8" link="fedora.com/8" information="fedora.com/8/more_info" / >
< os owner="Fedora" version="Fedora core 9" link="fedora.com/9" information="fedora.com/9/more_info" / >
< os owner="Fedora" version="Fedora core 10" link="fedora.com/10"  information="fedora.com/10/more_info" / >
< os owner="Redhat" version="Redhat 4" link="redhat.com/4"  information="redhat.com/4/more_info" / >
< os owner="Redhat" version="Redhat 5" link="redhat.com/5"  information="redhat.com/5/more_info" / >
< os owner="Redhat" version="Redhat 6" link="redhat.com/6"  information="redhat.com/6/more_info" / >
< os owner="Redhat" version="Redhat 7" link="redhat.com/7"  information="redhat.com/7/more_info" / >
< os owner="Redhat" version="Redhat 8" link="redhat.com/8"  information="redhat.com/8/more_info" / >
< os owner="Redhat" version="Redhat 9" link="redhat.com/9"  information="redhat.com/9/more_info" / >
< os owner="Redhat" version="Redhat 2010" link="redhat.com/2010"  information="redhat.com/2010/more_info" / >

I m already getting owner name as microsoft, now I want to show the versions,link and infomramtion of the particular owner

How can I pass the "microsoft" and show only the results of microsoft

How this can be done in Javascript
  Please help

Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for example to convert your xml data to DOM for example with respect of http://outwestmedia.com/jquery-plugins/xmldom/ jQuery plugin and use different jQuery selectors (see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to choose or find only the elements of XML which you need.

Another way could be converting your XML data to the JSON data with respect of a solution which you could find in the internet (see http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html for example). The JSON data can be convertet to JavaScript objects with `JSON.parse`. Then you can easy iterate through the javascript object without or with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Oleg,  I m able to load the xml. And Even I m able to load the owners in one dropdown by grouping their name. so after the owner name is selected other results are suppose to be shown.  Thanks

Comment: You can consider to load xml directly with respect of `jQuery.ajax` (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or `jQuery.get` (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Then you can easy to analyze the loaded xml data. In general I recommend you to use jQuery if you not yet do this already.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.  The solution is I need to run a for loop (i=0;i<xyz.length;i++)

and inside loop, i'll be checking for the values of i with if statement. and that'll filter the results.

This Idea was suggested by one of the subscriber at stackoverflow  

Thanks all of you again

Answer (score 0):

if your information is in XML i guess you could use xpath with something like

```
//os[@owner="microsoft"]/
```

the problem is that you would have to use a library or something to execute xpath queries in JS (http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp)... i think that MooTools can load an xml to the DOM and then use selectors like

```
$$('os[owner="microsoft"]')
```

I am not really sure about that one... and my last guess is that you could use regular expresions to do extract the lines

Comment: yes you are correct. all information is coming from xml only. and if possible I m ready to go ahead with jquery :)

Thanks